# What challenges may be foreseen to adapting the Wittman Tailwind as an E-LSA?

Tags: homebuilt, wittman-tailwind

The [Wittman Tailwind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittman_Tailwind) is a great performing aircraft which can be built on a budget.  Many potential builders have considered adapting the design as a light sport aircraft.  What challenges could be expected in getting this design to meet the LSA requirements?

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times in a traditional format.  I posted this question to illustrate the effectiveness of aviation stack exchange to users of the forum for exchanging technical information.